# Matlab set param from array

Tags: matlab, for-loop, simulink

In Matlab, in order to change the value of a block I do

```
set_param('model/V','Amplitude','100')
```

and the value of `V` is 100. But if I do

```
for i=1:10
     set_param('model/V','Amplitude','P(i)')
     ...
end
```

The it stores the value of `V` as `P(i)`. But in order to access the `i`-th element of the 20-by-1 `P` matrix, I need to refer to it by `P(i)`. What is my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the value to string using:-

```
set_param('model/V','Amplitude',num2str(P(i)) );
```

Also it will set the value of 'model/V' to P(20) i.e. last one.

You might want to loop through the current blocks too

Something like : (just example)

```
set_param(['model/V' num2str(i)],'Amplitude',num2str(P(i)) );
```

for `model/V1, model/V2,...model/V20` .

Comment: Oh it worked. But why did I need to convert it to string? Just wondering

Comment: @HS Well that's how the `ObjectParameters` values of most of simulink blocks are set.

Comment: This answer assumes that you want to put the numeric value of the i-th element of the variable P in the parameter dialog box.  Typically that is not what you want to do.  Typically you want to parameterize the model by putting the string 'P(i)' into the dialog (which is what the code in the original question does) then, assuming variable's P and i exist in the MATLAB Workspace when the model gets simulated, Simulink will pick up the numeric value at that time.